# Do wavelets at a given scale $2^j$ sum up to 0 when summing over all discrete translations of size $n$?

Tags: wavelet

suppose I have a wavelet $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\int \psi(t)dt=0$. Do we also have that for all $j\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$
\langle f\,,\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \psi_{j,n}(t) \rangle = 0
$$
where $\psi_{j,n}(t)= 2^{-j/2}\psi\left(2^{-j}(t-n)\right)$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is some square integrable function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No. Your expression is equivalently the sum of the *sampling of* convolution of $f$ and $\psi$ (rather cross-correlation). If it was just continuous-time convolution, then "yes": by convolution theorem, the DC bin (sum) of any wavelet is 0, so the DC bin of the convolution is also 0. The sampling however produces aliasing, meaning higher frequencies fold onto (sum on top of) lower, including DC.

This effect is seen in scipy's implementation of CWT, which samples wavelets in time instead of frequency domain. What should be done in discrete is to sample the wavelet in frequency, forcing DC to 0, then the discrete variants of your expression are true. So the following are true:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) \psi_{j, \tau}(t)d\tau \right)dt = 0,\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(t)dt = 0
$$

$$
\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} f[n] \psi_{j, n}[m]\right) = 0, \ \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \psi_{j}[m] = 0
$$

Note the dependence on $j$ in the discrete case: it's not enough for the mother wavelet to be zero-mean. Also, since wavelets are usually non-compact in frequency, your expression is pretty much never exactly true, but it is often very close to true, as wavelets are sparse in frequency (decay rapidly).

Comment: It's not quite that simple. The sequence is sampled and decimated and there is aliasing. So the continuous time integral does not have to match the discrete time sequence sum.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Hmm yes, it's sampling of CT convolution. Usually we don't care for this mixed formulation, if all's done in discrete or CT then it works out. Thanks.